# socket program to add integers in c

Tags: c, sockets

Can any one please tell me how can we send integers from client to server and add them 
  in c.

I was able to send strings successfully  but i am not able to figure out how to send 
  integers.

Please help me out!! The below written code was for reading strings. How can i change it
  it to read and add integers.

```
#define SOCK_PATH "echo_socket"

int main(void)
{

 int s, t, len;
 struct sockaddr_un remote;
 char str[100];
 if ((s = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
 perror("socket");
 exit(1);
}

 printf("Trying to connect...\n");
 remote.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
 strcpy(remote.sun_path, SOCK_PATH);
 len = strlen(remote.sun_path) + sizeof(remote.sun_family);


 int val=connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, len);

 if ( val< 0) {
 perror("connect");
 exit(1);
 }

 printf("Connected.\n");

 printf("ENTER THE NUMBERS:");

while(printf("> "), fgets(str, 100, stdin), !feof(stdin)) {

if (send(s, str, strlen(str), 0) == -1) {
perror("send");
exit(1);
}
if ((t=recv(s, str, 100, 0)) > 0) {
str[t] = '\0';
 printf("echo> %s", str);
} else 
{
  if (t < 0) perror("recv");
  else printf("Server closed connection\n");
  exit(1);
 }
```

}

Comment: First, you try something, then, if that doesn't work, tell us what you tried.

Comment: hey can u tell me what sock_path is in unix....i am getting totally confused...i am getting an error " Socket operation on non-socket"...does this path hold the structure we define and where to store the structure!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple:

```
int my_int = 1234;
send(socket, &my_int, sizeof(my_int), 0);
```

The above code sends the integer *as is* over the socket. To receive it on the other side:

```
int my_int;
recv(socket, &my_int, sizeof(my_int), 0);
```

However, be careful if the two programs runs on systems with different byte order.

**Edit:** If you worry about platform compatibilities, byte ordering and such, then converting all data to strings on one end and then convert it back on the other, might be the best choice. See e.g. the answer from cnicutar.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sprintf` to turn them into strings and then `strtoul` to turn them back into integers. Or you can just `memcpy` integers to and from a char array.

Comment: hey can u tell me what sock_path is in unix....i am getting totally confused...i am getting an error " Socket operation on non-socket"...does this path hold the structure we define and where to store the structure!!

Comment: i have posted my entire client side code...i an getting the same error on both sides(client and server)...please help...i dont get sock_path part??